# How to get all files from a media library in kentico?

Tags: file, search, kentico, media-library

I want to save all files paths inside of a media library folder in kentico.
I found this code for one file but I don't know which Class to use to get all content any advice, please.

```
 MediaFileInfo updateFile = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(library.LibraryID, "NewFolder/Image.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

This should get all the files in a specific media library.

```
var files = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFiles().Where("FileLibraryID",QueryOperator.Equals, library.LibraryID);
```